# Elixir for Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cpython, python-elixir

I have a problem installing Elixir with Python 3 although I have installed SqlAlchemy 0.7.3 successfully? I've tried google-ing but I am loosing hope. Is there really a version of Elixir for Python 3? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/browser), I see that the [latest change](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/log/) happened 10 months ago. Also, searching for `print` I see that all the strings found in all branches use `print` as a statement, not as a function and there isn't any log string that makes a reference to python 3.

Hence, since I don't see any trace of work towards supporting python 3, I'd say there's no Elixir for Python 3 unless that work is hosted in a different location.

Edit: As pointed out by a comment, in `setup.py` there's some useful information. In particular, for python3 2to3 is executed to generate a python3 version of the code. Note that this depends completely on 2to3 and doesn't guarantee that the final result is going to work fine.

Comment: You forgot to check setup.py.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check that. However, from what I see, running 2to3 and hope that everything works fine isn't what I would call a python3 version of elixir as it was asked in the question.

Comment: It does seems unlikely that this would work. But on the other hand, why check it in if it doesn't? So it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated my answer with a comment regarding `setup.py`. I agree on that, as a last resort, it's worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There has been work done on Elixir to support Python 3, but Elixir has not seen a release with this work included. I'm not involved in Elixir and do not know the status of this work, but you might want to try to use a checkout of the latest [source code](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/browser/elixir).

If that works, you should badger the [authors](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki/Contact) into making a release.

If it doesn't work, you should join the mailing list and help port it. It's usually not very difficult.